# Parse - limit result of a Query in Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Hello is this code in the comment possible with Parse Cloud Code?

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeFind('Note', function(req) {
    var query = req.query; 
    var user = req.user; 
    // if a given 'Note' visibility is set to 'Unlisted' 
    // return only the Notes with 'user' field that the calling _User 
});
```

The [documentation](http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#beforefind-triggers) only shows how to filter fields that are returned but not exactly remove items from the query result in the Cloud Code.

This can be done through ACL, I know, but the caveat is that if the request is a *retrieve* function and not *query* the Note should still return.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've saved the user as an object relationship (not a string id).  Just add the qualification you need, such as:

```
query.equalTo("your_user_pointer_col_on_Note", user)
```

Comment: Apparently, this will not prevent the end-user to retrieve "Unlisted" items when the end-user (client) does its own Parse query without this `equalTo` filter. My goal is to prevent the client to gain access to "Unlisted" items without knowing the objectId of that item.

Comment: @xybrek -  I think I understand now that the question is about struggling with the specific logic as opposed just how to modify a query (I was answering the latter).  In order to answer the former, please clarify what's logically required.   Do you want unlisted notes where user = caller, and all "listed" notes, no matter the user?  That's doable.  Can you add some words about about what the listed field looks like (name, is it on the note or the user model, what values can it take) and what you mean logically exactly (if its different than what I just proposed)?

Comment: Notes have 3 views, Public, Private and Unlisted, the Private view was easy just set the ACL to the User and then that's done. The Public view also is easy--set the ACL to Public Read, the problem is with the Unlisted, it has to be accessible if the ObjectId is known if not it should not return for a GET query to `classes/Note` only the Public notes should be returned. However as mentioned, if the ObjectId of the Unlisted note is known then it should be accessible.